# parent div click function not run if i click to child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

HI i have face to one issue in my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.rohit', function() {
    alert('rohit');
  })

  $(document).on('click', '.azad', function() {
    alert('azad');
  })

});
```

```css
.rohit {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.azad {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rohit">
  hello
  <div class="azad">
    hello azad
  </div>
</div>
```

if i click to azad div than rohit div also trigger alert how to stop to this

i m using to this seriousness in angular js

Comment: Can you please fix your sintax error in your code?

Comment: Use stopPropagation, every day same questions!

Comment: i know about this but this is not workign in angualr js

Comment: So you should've exposed the problem as if it were related to angularjs, all you're using on your example is jQuery, angularjs usually have a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to avoid triggering the listener of the parent element:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      
      $(document).on('click','.rohit', function(){
          alert('rohit');
      })
      
      $(document).on('click', '.azad',function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();
          alert('azad');
      })
      
});
```

```css
.rohit{width:200px;height:100px;background:green;}

.azad{width:100px;height:50px; background:gray;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rohit">
    hello <div  class="azad">
    hello azad
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use event `stopPropagation()` method. This method prevents the event propagation to the parents.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on('click','.rohit', function(e){
      alert('rohit');
  })

  $(document).on('click', '.azad',function(e){
      e.stopPropagation()
      alert('azad');

  })
});
```

Here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/9c54tow6/